# What is the JSON format to specify multiple "sources" under AWS::CloudFormation::Init?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services

As per the [AWS CloudFormation documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-sources), I simply added a `,` and added more sources for multiple zip files.

When I launched the stack only the last source (zip file) was downloaded and unzipped in the right location, all others were simply ignored.

Probably my JSON is wrong. Anyone ?

Comment: `"sources" : 
{ 
"C:\\folder1\\folder2\\" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/folder/myservices1.zip",
"C:\\folder1\\folder2\\" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/folder/myservices2.zip"
}`

What I expect are two new folders under folder2 called myservices1 and myservices2 with their unzipped content in it. However, I see only myservices2.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting ! arrrgh !

Comment: Is it such that only ONE zip file is allowed to download ?!?!?! That would be ridiculous !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a reply from AWS.

You cannot have a the two keys of the same kind, e.g. above the two keys are "C:\folder1\folder2\" and "C:\folder1\folder2\". They must be different.

So I changed one of the "C:\folder1\folder2\" to "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3" and changed my zip file to accommodate this change such that finally the contents will be in the right folder structure.